# Cannot connect to wired internet Dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: 11.04, dell, ethernet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dell inspiron 1545 wired and wireless do not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99775/dell-inspiron-1545-wired-and-wireless-do-not-work)

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 and when I connect the internet cable, Network manager does not recognizes it... I am a beginner!