# Dell inspiron 1545 wired and wireless do not work

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, ethernet

When I realized my wireless wasn't working with ubuntu, I plugged my laptop in to try and figure out the problem online - only to find it doesn't work that way, either. The problem isn't my internet/ cords because I'm using both right now via my wireless desktop.

I'm just getting in to ubuntu and would appreciate any assistance. I've looked around but the only similar questions I could find were about the wireless problem - but I have to deal with the wired problem, first.

Let me know what info I need to give.

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A2
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02aa] 
    Kernel driver in use: sky2 -- 
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c] 
    Kernel modules: ssb

~$ rfkill list all 
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: yes
```

The output of `lsmod`: http://pastebin.com/DqNwKcqZ

Comment: Any info about the wired/wireless hardware and drivers would be most welcome. In case you know nothing about it, open a terminal window (ctrl+alt+t), then type, or better copy/paste `lspci -knn | grep -i net -A2`, `lsmod` and `rfkill list all`, and let us see its outputs. Since that laptop doesn't have an internet connection, I hope you have a USB stick to save the outputs into a text files.

Comment: I hope this is an ok way to share the info (If there's some form of formatting the site requires, sorry!) But anyway, yeah, there are the three things you said to look up. Thanks, by the way, @mikewhatever

Comment: Ouch! The comment section wasn't the best place for outputs. :~) You can try installing the wireless driver from the installation CD/USB. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#STA_-_No_Internet_access

Comment: @Jacob All the useful information is in the question now, can you remove those comments so it's not so confusing? (Click the X next to each one). From now on as you do research just keep editing the question itself, thanks!

Comment: Looks like the wireless has a solution here, but we probably need the wired one working first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45598/where-to-get-dell-inspiron-1545-drivers-for-the-dell-1397-wlan-minicard-wireless

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro . Sorry for the mess! So the link points to the wireless solution like you said. Anyone know about the wired problem? The wired network connection indicator (icon... thing) seems to... blink, I guess, but it doesn't actually connect at all. I don't know if that means anything.

Comment: @Jacob I'm on a Inspiron 1545, and I can confirm that the bcmwl-kernel-source thing works. If it doesn't you'd need to uninstall the package, and install it using jockey (Additional Drivers).

For the wired network, this may sound dumb, but does your network require a static IP address? You made need to configure it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Please try downloading the driver for Linux 2.6 here: http://www.marvell.com/support/downloads/driverDownload.do?driverId=153&action=1
Run install.sh in a terminal, that should fix the problem, it did for the guy in my source.
Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575197 Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The Inspiron 1545 has been certified with Ubuntu since 10.10, with the exact components you describe, so it should work and the hardware should be compatible.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200912-4896

To get the wireless card to work you may need to install additional drivers; for this you'd need the wired network to be working.

One other strange thing is your rfkill output; the hardware should not appear as "hard-blocked", this indicates the wireless switch is in the "disabled" position. Double-check that it's on "enabled". Also, try `rmmod dell-laptop`, and see if the rfkill status changes. If so, please let me know, as this shouldn't happen on this laptop model.

As for the wired network, that should work out of the box and with no problems. To diagnose this, I suggest you unplug the cable, restart the system, and run `tail -f /var/log/syslog` on a terminal. Then plug in the cable and look at the log output, to see exactly what happens when you connect this. If you have trouble interpreting the output, you could also pastebin the last lines of the system log and we can look at it to see if we can suggest something else.

Answer (score 0):

I have the wireless portion of this issue solved on my Vostro 1720. It can be found here: [Broadcom 4312 wireless issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102282/broadcom-4312-wireless-issues/102388#102388)

### Earlier posting:

I just figured this one out again... (I've got the same 1397 WLAN Mini-Card, BCM4312) after a buncha tinkering in the forums and whatnot.

I'm not entirely what SPECIFICALLY fixed it but i do know some of the last things i did were went to http://www.marvell.com/support/downloads/search.do# and snagged Kernel 2.6.x Linux Driver Install Package for Yukon Devices. I followed the directions included in the Readme file as far as installing the tarball.

After I had that installed i reactivated my bcmwl-kernel-source driver and did some good ol `sudo rmmod dell-laptop` (putting yourself in sudo -s ive found makes root actions easier).

Rebooted this piece and stuff lit all up and wireless is blazing! Now to fix the injection issue.... hopefully! Happy Hunting and I hoped this helped!