# Broadcom 4312 wireless issues

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I know theres a plethora of other questions and some are "Solved" out there for this same issue but I've run through all that I can find to no avail.

I solved this problem once but then I went on to troubleshoot an injection issue fora nother program and I messed up the wireless so I reinstalled and now I can't get it working again!  On this reload of Ubuntu 11.10 ive already tried a couple things so ill post as much relevant info as I know.

I'm new to Linux entirely having only used it for about a week now.

```
LSPCI:
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ICH9M/M-E SATA AHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
0e:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
1a:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): O2 Micro, Inc. Device 10f7 (rev 01)
1a:00.1 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8120 (rev 01)
1a:00.2 Mass storage controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8130 (rev 01)


iwconfig:
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
ifconfig:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:e8:bb:67:b9  
          inet addr:192.168.5.109  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:e8ff:febb:67b9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13807 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9503 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15997294 (15.9 MB)  TX bytes:1087286 (1.0 MB)
          Interrupt:46 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4672 (4.6 KB)  TX bytes:4672 (4.6 KB)
```

If any other information is needed please let me know. Again thank you for your time!

```
Additional information:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up;iwconfig;
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0

lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2:

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02c0]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
0e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

rfkill list:
0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

If I do put on the proprietary driver (which I've read in several forums to remove) it still doesn't let me use my wireless. As it currently stands I have it activated and I still have for my rfkill:

0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
```

1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

I tried the solutions here and they did not work:

- [Dell inspiron 1545 wired and wireless do not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99775/dell-inspiron-1545-wired-and-wireless-do-not-work)

Additional Information: If you have the interface Eth2 or something similar and can't set your card to `monitor mode` then

1. Open your package manager and search for `bcm`
2. Uninstall that crap
3. Make sure you have the `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` and `b43-fwcutter` while youre  there.
4. Type into terminal

   ```
    cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep 'bcm'
   ```

   and see if the term `blacklist bcm43xx` is there.
5. If it is, type

   ```
   cd /etc/modprobe.d/
   sudo gedit blacklist.conf
   ```

   put a # in front of the line: `blacklist bcm43xx` then save the file (you might get some funky messages saying that it isnt saving, it should be ok)
6. Reboot
7. You may have to re-apply the previous command:

   ```
   sudo rmmod dell-laptop
   ```

I believe you have to blacklist wl as well as it wont let you get into monitor mode and you want it replaced by the kernel driver b43-pci-bridge as stated in the following code:

```
     lspci -nnk | grep -i net -a2
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02c0]
    Kernel modules: i2c-i801
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02c0]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0e:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: The duplicate has the same symptoms and same mini-card.

Comment: Foss i followed the directions of the 2 "Answers" and still got nuffin. When i run rmmod dell-laptop it doesnt let me, says access restricted or something, at that my LAN is working in linux just not the wireless. I have to keep going from Win 7 to Ubuntu to diagnose all this. Ive currently got the Marvell driver loaded as far as i know and the proprietary if. After activating the proprietary driver the WLAN light popped on but im still Hard and Soft blocked. The WLAN button is set to the "ON" position. >.<

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this one out again. Now again >.< I'm now fairly certain as to what fixed this.

Actually there's still one step I question the relevance of, though I'm sure in the end it's worth doing regardless and that is to get all possible updates through your software manager.

Next if you don't already have Synaptic Package Manager get it. In Synaptic, make sure you have

`bcm-kernel-source`, `b43-fwcutter`, and depending on your chipset (in this case) `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`.

Next you want to go to terminal and put in `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and scroll right on down to

```
## # replaced by b43 and ssb.
##blacklist bcm43xx
```

So you can put a # right next to blacklist bcm43xx so you end up with:

```
## #blacklist bcm43xx
```

Go ahead and reboot to get all this loaded up. After the reboot you go to terminal and your `rfkill list` should produce Hard or soft blocked to some degree (both were blocked for me). To fix this type in:

```
#sudo -s
#rmmod dell-laptop
```

Putting yourself in `sudo -s` I've found makes root actions easier.

Rebooted this piece and stuff lit all up and wireless is blazing! I did notice that my proprietary driver that Linux wanted to install initially is activated.

Answer (score 0):

That's the LP-PHY model like on my dell 1747, so you'll need the `lp-phy b43` driver, which looks like you might have already.

Make sure you remove any b43 driver previously installed through 'additional drivers' or via apt.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge b43-fwcutter
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
ifconfig eth2
```

If that doesn't work then purge that driver, `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Then install this one `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer`

Some say that one works for them where the bcmwl does not.

Comment: already had bcmwl-kernel-source. doesnt b43 ip-phy need the b43 fwcutter? Also last time when i had my wireless working the wireless interface i was using was wlan0 >.<

Comment: ... you might want to look at the duplicate and add your answer there - you might be able to claim the bounty as well!

Comment: what do you mean the duplicate foss?

Comment: using the proprietary driver uses ethX, at least it always has for the machines I used with broadcom lp-phy devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the network card switches are inhibiting your connection.

1. Make completely sure there is not a hardware switch keeping your network card off.
2. Run `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`. This should remove every *soft block* related to your network card.
   Please check this and report back. If this doesn't happen, perhaps your computer doesn't let both wireless virtual devices to be active at the same time.
3. I recommend you to blacklist your `dell_laptop` module. This was giving me wireless connection problems once too.

   `sudo echo dell_laptop >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-<username>.conf`
4. Make sure you only have one network card driver loaded at a time. The drivers that are used for your network card popularly are: `wl`, `b43` and `ssb`. Find out how to do this in more detail at the [bcm43xx article @ Ubuntu Community Documentation Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx).

   - Load drivers with `sudo modprobe <driver>`
   - Unload drivers with `sudo modprobe -r <driver>`
   - Check for a loaded driver with `lsmod | grep <driver>`
5. Once you have a working configuration, be sure to add the working driver to the `/etc/modules/` file:

   `sudo echo <driver> >> /etc/modules`, where driver can be either of `wl`, `b43` and `ssb`
6. Blacklist the modules that didn't work:

   `sudo echo <driver> >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-<username>.conf`